# Is there a way to only return the ID from this Laravel Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have run a query to get my specific needs but it's returning a whole bunch of array,
Is there a way to get only the specific column i needed?

This is what i am trying

```
 $datas = DB::table('tableA')
                    ->select('tableA.id')
                    ->rightJoin('tableB','tableA.id','=','tableB.tableAt_id')
                    ->where('tableB.active',1)
                    ->whereIn('tableB.status',$myArray)
                    ->get();
```

and the output is

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1349 ▼
  #items: array:221 [▼
    0 => {#1327 ▼
      +"id": 2020010201
    }
    1 => {#1346 ▼
      +"id": 2020010202
    }
    2 => {#1343 ▼
      +"id": 2020011501
    }
```

I only want the ID. i tried toArray() but its the same

Comment: don't do `dd()` just return the value you will get only `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pluck.

Your code should be.

```
$datas = DB::table('tableA')
                    ->rightJoin('tableB','tableA.id','=','tableB.tableAt_id')
                    ->where('tableB.active',1)
                    ->whereIn('tableB.status',$myArray)
                    ->pluck('tableA.id');
```

[Read More about Pluck Method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck)

Comment: That did it! i tried it first using pluck and toArray, but never thought about just using pluck. Thanks!